# How can I update a tkinter progress bar to show the progress of a song in a playlist using pygame and mutagen?

Tags: tkinter, customtkinter

I need the progress bar to change depending on the song.

```py
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

import customtkinter as ctk
import pygame
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import pygame.event

class AudioPlayer:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Audio Player")
        master.geometry("400x250")

        self.play_button = ctk.CTkButton(master, text='     ▶️', command=self.play, width=60, height=50)
        self.pause_button = ctk.CTkButton(master, text='| |', command=self.pause, width=60, height=50)
        self.next_button = ctk.CTkButton(master, text='⏩', command=self.next, width=60, height=50)
        self.prev_button = ctk.CTkButton(master, text='⏪', command=self.prev, width=60, height=50)
        self.track_info_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master, text='')

        self.pause_button.place(x=190, y=50)
        self.play_button.place(x=120, y=50)

        self.next_button.place(x=260, y=50)
        self.prev_button.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.track_info_label.pack(pady=10, padx=20)

        self.volume_scale = ctk.CTkSlider(master, from_=0, to=100, command=self.set_volume)
        self.volume_scale.set(50.0)
        self.volume_scale.place(x=170, y=110)

        self.load_button = ctk.CTkButton(master, text='Load', command=self.load_file, width=100, height=25)
        self.load_button.place(x=50, y=110)

        self.progress_bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(master, orientation=ctk.HORIZONTAL, corner_radius=200, mode='determinate', width=270, height=25)
        self.progress_bar.place(x=50, y=145)

        self.playlist = []
        self.current_track_index = -1

        pygame.mixer.init()
        self.update_progress_bar()

    def load_file(self):
        directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.playlist = []
        if directory_path:
            for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
                for filename in filenames:
                    if filename.endswith('.mp3'):
                        self.playlist.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

    def play(self):
        if len(self.playlist) > 0:
            if self.current_track_index == -1:
                self.current_track_index = 0
                pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist[self.current_track_index])
                self.update_track_info()
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

            self.update_progress_bar()


    def next(self):
        if len(self.playlist) > 0:
            self.current_track_index = (self.current_track_index + 1) % len(self.playlist)
            self.update_track_info()
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist[self.current_track_index])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            self.progress_bar['value'] = 0

    def prev(self):
        if len(self.playlist) > 0:
            self.current_track_index = (self.current_track_index - 1) % len(self.playlist)
            self.update_track_info()
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlist[self.current_track_index])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            self.progress_bar['value'] = 0

    def update_track_info(self):
        if len(self.playlist) > 0:
            track_path = self.playlist[self.current_track_index]
            track_name = os.path.basename(track_path)
            self.track_info_label.configure(text=track_name[:-4])

    def pause(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    def set_volume(self, value):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(float(value) / 100)

    def update_progress_bar(self):
        if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            current_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000.0
            song_length = MP3(self.playlist[self.current_track_index]).info.length
            percent_elapsed = (current_time / song_length) * 100
            self.progress_bar['value'] = percent_elapsed
        self.master.after(1000, self.update_progress_bar)


root = ctk.CTk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

player = AudioPlayer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I don't understand how to do this, because I recently got acquainted with the library and never found an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a function that calls itself every 1 second and update the progress bar using an intvariable from custom tkinter

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
root = ctk.CTk()

def update_slider():
    current_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
    song_length = MP3(song_address).info.length
    slider_var.set(current_time)
    slider_var.configure(to = int(song_length))
    root.after(1000, update_slider)


slider_var = ctk.IntVar(value=0)
slider = ctk.ctkslider(root, from_ = 0, to = 1)

root.mainloop()
```